# Change cell contents if it contains a certain letter

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a column that lists the race/ethnicity of individuals. I am trying to make it so that if the cell contains an 'H' then I only want H. Similarly, if the cell contains an 'N' then I want an N. Finally, if the cell has multiple races, not including H or N, then I want it to be M. Below is how it is listed currently and the desired output.

```
Current output

People | Race/Ethnicity

PersonA| HAB
PersonB| NHB
PersonC| AB
PersonD| ABW
PersonE| A

Desired output
PersonA| H
PersonB| N
PersonC| M
PersonD| M
PersonE| A
```

Comment: The `NHB` cell (row 2) contains an `H` and `N`- could you clarify why it is `N`? Do you mean if the first letter is an H/N?

Comment: No, if the cell contains N anywhere in the cell I want the result to be N. Likewise, if the cell has an H anywhere in the cell I want H, only to be superseded by N. Lastly, if the cell contains more than two races, but neither H or N, then I want the result to be M

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following `dplyr` approach, which combines `grepl` with `dplyr::case_when` to first search for `N` values, then among those not with `N` values, search for `H` values, then among those without an `H` or an `N` will assign `M` to those with >1 races and the original letter to those with only one race (assuming each race is represented by a single character).

A base R approach is below as well - no need for dependencies but but less elegant.

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "person ethnicity 
PersonA HAB
PersonB NHB
PersonC AB
PersonD ABW
PersonE A", header = TRUE)
```

dplyr (note order matters given your priority)

```
df %>% mutate(eth2 = case_when(
  grepl("N", ethnicity) ~ "N",
  grepl("H", ethnicity) ~ "H",
  !grepl("H|N", ethnicity) & nchar(ethnicity) > 1 ~ "M",
  TRUE ~ ethnicity
))
```

You could also do it "manually" in base r by indexing (note order matters given your priority):

```
df[grepl("H", df$ethnicity), "eth2"] <- "H"
df[grepl("N", df$ethnicity), "eth2"] <- "N"
df[!grepl("H|N", df$ethnicity) & nchar(df$ethnicity) > 1, "eth2"] <- "M"
df[nchar(df$ethnicity) %in% 1, "eth2"] <- df$ethnicity[nchar(df$ethnicity) %in% 1]
```

In both cases the output is:

```
#    person ethnicity eth2
# 1 PersonA       HAB    H
# 2 PersonB       NHB    N
# 3 PersonC        AB    M
# 4 PersonD       ABW    M
# 5 PersonE         A    A
```

Note this is based on your comment about assigning superiority (that `N` anywhere supersedes those with both `N` and `H`, etc)

Answer (score 2):

We could use `str_extract`.  When the number of characters in the column is greater than 1, extract, the 'N', 'M' separately, do a `coalesce` with the extracted elements along with 'M' (thus if there is no match, we get 'M', or else it will be in the order we placed the inputs in `coalecse`, For the other case, i.e. number of characters is 1, return the column values.  Thus, `N` supersedes 'H' no matter the position in the string.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(output = case_when(nchar(`Race/Ethnicity`) > 1 
   ~ coalesce(str_extract(`Race/Ethnicity`, 'N'), 
              str_extract(`Race/Ethnicity`, 'H'), "M"), 
    TRUE ~ `Race/Ethnicity`))
```

-output

```
   People Race/Ethnicity output
1 PersonA            HAB      H
2 PersonB            NHB      N
3 PersonC             AB      M
4 PersonD            ABW      M
5 PersonE              A      A
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(People = c("PersonA", "PersonB", "PersonC", "PersonD", 
"PersonE"), `Race/Ethnicity` = c("HAB", "NHB", "AB", "ABW", "A"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Does this code make it so that N takes priority over H? If a cell contains N at all I would like for it to say N even if H is contained within it

Comment: @ConnorHill Yes, this takes the priority as you mentioned and it gives the output as you showed as expected